# Solution to Find string from a list , to another string VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

What I would like to do is, I have an excel where I load every day some football, tennis

[Daily List] : https://www.dropbox.com/s/45ulku7val6q6lj/sample.jpg?dl=0
[image]

Additionally I have another excel file/sheet with some Name of Tennis Players, Football Teams Names, Football Leagues in this format :

[RedList] : https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9nqx2zpq696o38/redlist.jpg
[image]

Of course i can change the format of this list is just a test list.

Now what i actually want to do is to check from second list (Red List) if any of the teams names appear on the main sheet names and highlight the row, but i am facing some issues to some additional parameters .

One way that i tried to do that was with a SUMPRODUCT Function something like that :

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A4,"*"&$F$2:$F$6&"*"))=0,"None Found",INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$6,A4)),),0)))
```

Which works fine but its not working perfectly cause for instance if i have in red list the name Yankel Zemel , and in daily list the name appears as Yankel Z, or Zemel Yankel, or Zemel Y. , the function will return False.

Another issue could be the comma between the two names OR some special characters Anif / Salzburg II , ASKÖ Gmünd, Blau-Weiß Linz ... etc

So i tried to figure out how i could solve this problem.

One solution to use Find in VBA but again im not sure if that would work.
Another solution but a little bit more tricky would be to create an access database and try to store there different versions of each name, so for instance
Zemel Yankel = Yankel Zemel = Yankel Z = Zemel Y. = yankel, zemel etc rename them to a unique name for instance Zemel Yankel. The truth is that i dont know if that would be easy to do it as i dont have a lot of knowledge to do it in access and i dont know if that is a good solution too.

Another solution but i have no idea again about it, is to use regExp

Did I ask too much ? How you would solve this problem ?

Comment: This is a very common problem that is not that easy to solve. What you could start with is converting everything to lower case and removing any characters like . or , 
This will still give you a problem with initials instead of first names and the order in which the names are written. For this you could create a lookup table and use the lookup function in Excel.
I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tom mentioned it is not an easy problem but with slight twist you can achieve what you want. I recently did a similar project as yours where I employed this method and the client is pretty happy with the arrangement.

Create a new sheet called, say, `Alias` and maintain a table there. Something like this. So whenever you come across an alias, simply put that in the table. With these football games, you will not come across more than 10 aliases (*as far as what I have seen till date*). However if you do come across more names then simply update the table.

[image]

Now use your `.Find` to loop through the aliases to find a match.

You can also try and evaluate the formula in VBA code when you are looping through aliases. For example

```
Dim rngAlias As Range

'~~> Hard coding. This is where you will loop through the range
Set rngAlias = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Alias").Range("A2")

'sFormula = "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(" & _
           "A4" & _
           ",""*""&$F$2:$F$6&""*""))=0,""None Found""," & _
           "INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$6," & _
           "A4" & _
           ")),),0)))"

sFormula = "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(" & _
           rngAlias.Address & _
           ",""*""&$F$2:$F$6&""*""))=0,""None Found""," & _
           "INDEX($F$2:$F$6,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$6," & _
           rngAlias.Address & _
           ")),),0)))"
```

Hope this gets you started!